# How one category can have different fields?

Tags: theme-development, themes

*I am new in WordPress but before I worked with Drupal and it is different and I am a little confusing now.*

I am going to make a website for a **travel agency,** and one of the categories that they have is hotel. That is list of hotels that should sort by name of cities. then when I click on one city's link, **they want to show the list of hotels of that city sort by their rating.**

*I really don't know a lot about WordPress and I get confusing, and I don't know what should I do.*

I want to have a category that is about hotels, and let the editor of website to post a hotel and fill out some different fields about hotel. **fields like** stars, city, country, address ...

*In Drupal, that was easier by **views**, but I like to learn WordPress and the website should be in WordPress. In Drupal it is really easy to add custom fields*

Please show me a way and I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very *very* rough guess at what data architecture for it might look in WordPress would be:

- hotel is a Custom Post Type (individual items of something)
- city is a term of custom taxonomy (group of items)
- stars and similar data are custom fields (specific data attached to items)

However there are numerous nuances in all of this, which is WP development essentially consists of. :)

WP also isn't particularly helpful about building UIs for custom things. Taxonomies more or less have UI provided, but with custom fields you are mosly on your own. On other hand there are dozens of third party frameworks around that aim to help with building out just that.

Comment: Do you know any solution for it?

Comment: Solution for what? There are a lot of ways to do this, probability I can guess what is perfectly right from brief high level description of your requirements is pretty much zero.

Comment: You said Custom post type, custom taxonomy and custom fields. How to make these? should I install plugin or something? Can you please share a link of instruction for this- And yes my knowledge is pretty much zero :(

Comment: Covering all of this would be way too long for an answer. All of them are sufficiently covered in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) (official WP documentation).

Comment: I will search for that. But let me know please, Should I write codes for making custom post type or it can be done by plugins?

Comment: The native way to define CPTs is via code, though there _are_ plugins areound that allow to do it via UI.

Comment: OK. thanks for your help. I searched and I found some plugins for this. But can you please suggest me one of the good plugins for this? (Because you are experienced)

Comment: Sorry, plugin suggestions are out of scope here. My choices won't necessarily be good fit for your preferences and requirements. There _are_ dozens of solid solutions for it _because_ it's hard to recommend/develop a single staple one that would fit all.